# Need help selecting the second child node and it's children with XPath in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to select the second child node off the root and all it's children from XML that looks similar to this:

```
<root>
   <SET>
      <element>
      <element>
   </SET>
   <SET>
      <element>
      <element>
   </SET>
<root>
```

I'm after all the  tags in the second  node, any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using C#. I tried the XPath /SET[1] however that didn't see to help!

Many thanks!

C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x/y[1] : 
     The first <y> child of each <x>. This is equivalent to the expression in the next row.

x/y[position() = 1] :The first <y> child of each <x>.
```

Try this :

```
string xpath = "/root/set[2]";
XmlNode locationNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

or

```
string xpath = "/root/set[position() = 2]";
XmlNode locationNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Comment: you can get more info about xpath over here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Answer (score 1):

XPath is not zero-index based, it's one-indexed.

You want: `root/set[2]`

Comment: Hi, old friend, you forgot the starting slash. :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(@"C:\testing.xml");

XmlNodeList sets = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SET");

//Show the value of first set's first element
Console.WriteLine(sets[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText);

//Show the value of second set's second element
Console.WriteLine(sets[1].ChildNodes[1].InnerText);
```