# Reading Xml with all attributes on one line

Tags: c#, xml

I see a lot of (apparently) working solutions for Xml-Files structured like this:

```
<Areas>
    <Area>
        <SetNr>"0"</SetNr>
        <X1>"283.06"</X1>
        <Y1>"-39.0490"</Y1>
        <X2>"289.17"</X2>
        <Y2>"-40.8466"</Y2>
        <Peak>"285.50"</Peak>
        <PeakArea>"44.860"</PeakArea>
        <DeltaH>"44.860"</DeltaH>
    </Area>
    <Area>
        <SetNr>"1"</SetNr>
        <X1>"277.68"</X1>
        <Y1>"-38.0286"</Y1>
        <X2>"280.94"</X2>
        <Y2>"-39.2697"</Y2>
        <Peak>"279.96"</Peak>
        <PeakArea>"9.411"</PeakArea>
        <DeltaH>"9.411"</DeltaH>
    </Area>
</Areas>
```

For this structure I find many examples ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764989/c-sharp-read-xml-file-and-select-nodes), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164731/need-help-selecting-the-second-child-node-and-its-children-with-xpath-in-c-shar) etc) (using <kbd>innerText</kbd>, <kbd>SelectSingleNode</kbd>, <kbd>GetElementsByTagName</kbd> etc) to read one <kbd><Area /Area></kbd>-Package after the other and accessing the X1/Y1/etc seperately.

But my Xml-File is structured like this:

```
<Areas>
    <Area SetNr="0" X1="283.06" Y1="-39.0490" X2="289.17" Y2="-40.8466" Peak="285.50" PeakArea="44.860" DeltaH="44.860" />
    <Area SetNr="1" X1="277.68" Y1="-38.0286" X2="280.94" Y2="-39.2697" Peak="279.96" PeakArea="9.411" DeltaH="9.411" />
</Areas>
```

For this structure the solutions from above don't work. Can anybody help me?

I am looking for a possibility to do something like this

```
for each(Area in Areas)
{
    mySetNr = Area.SetNr
    myX1 = Area.X1
    ...
    ...
}
```

or

```
mySetNr_0 = Area[0].SetNr
myX1_0 = Area[0].X1
...
...
mySetNr_1 = Area[1].SetNr
myX1_1 = Area[1].X1
...
...
```

*(I am aware that mySetNr_0 etc is a very bad way to handle it, this is just to keep my question as short as possible. In my real code I will obviously work with lists)*

Comment: Would looking at the different mainstream standards help?, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083727/how-to-create-xml-in-c-sharp

Comment: "SetNr", "Y1", so on, are XML attributes, so you want to search for ways to read XML attribute in C#..

Comment: What real code do you have so far?

Comment: If you are using [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0), mark your properties `SetNr`, `X1` and so on with [`[XmlAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattribute) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11330786) by Darin Dimitrov to [Serialize Property as Xml Attribute in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11330643).  Also see [Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123648) for general guidance on serializing to XML in c#.

Answer (score 0):

I am handling it now like this. It works, but I am not really happy with it tbh:

```
// Parameters from my function
string xElements = "Areas";
string xElement = "Area";


XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xPath + xFile);
foreach (var itemElement in xDoc.Element(xElements).Elements(xElement))
{
    var x = itemElement.Attributes();
    var xx = x.ToList();

    List<string> xAttributes = new List<string>();
    List<string> xValues = new List<string>();
    string[] xValue = new String[] { };
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Count(); i++)
    {
        xAttributes.Add(xx[i].Name.ToString());
        xValues.Add(xx[i].Value.ToString()); 
    }
    writeRow2Access(dbLocation, dbTable, xAttributes, xValues); // further usage of the values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=d4hsA9m3zg).

```
var strXml =@"<Areas> " +
                "<Area SetNr=\"0\" X1=\"283.06\" Y1=\"-39.0490\" X2=\"289.17\" Y2=\"-40.8466\" Peak=\"285.50\" PeakArea=\"44.860\" DeltaH=\"44.860\" /> " +
                "<Area SetNr=\"1\" X1=\"277.68\" Y1=\"-38.0286\" X2=\"280.94\" Y2=\"-39.2697\" Peak=\"279.96\" PeakArea=\"9.411\" DeltaH=\"9.411\" />" +
                "</Areas>";
            XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(strXml);
            var tables = x.Descendants("Area");
            
            foreach (var areaAttributes in tables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(areaAttributes.Attribute("SetNr").ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(areaAttributes.Attribute("X1").ToString());
            };
```